# Install composer on debian when behind a proxy stuck on downloading

Tags: php, composer-php

I modified several things already on my debian server that is behind a proxy:

- apt-get

  sudo vi /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy

  Acquire::http::Proxy "http://...";
- git

  alias curl="curl -x ..."

So now git and apt-get are working fine through proxy

Now I try to install composer with :

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

But it gets stuck at Downloading... then:
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
Retrying...

How can I get it to install through proxy and then have composer working fine behind proxy?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever try `export http_proxy=http://proxy.server.com:80`?

Comment: ok, sorry but it was a mistake between using the sudo or without sudo command. It needs to be included for both so that both would work.